# Let $n$ be a fixed integer and let $ H $ = {$x \in G : x^n = e$}. Prove that H is a subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be an abelian group and let $n$ be a fixed integer and let $ H $ = {$x \in G : x^n = e$}. Prove that H is a subgroup of G.

So firstly, $e \in G$ since the condition is that $x^n : e$.

I get confused about how to go further from here.

If we suppose that $a, b \in H$ then $a^n = e$ and $b^n=e$. But how do I get an expression for ab from here?

Sorry, I think I am confusing myself. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: You want to prove that if $a^n=e$ and $b^n=e$ then $(ab)^n=e$. So what is $(ab)^n$ in terms of $a^n$ and $b^n$?

Comment: Got it! Just realized I was being quite stupid. Thank you!

Comment: See also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965317/check-let-g-be-an-abelian-group-show-x-in-g-xn-e-for-some-n-in-math).